# Marionette CRUD examples

Tags: marionette

I am trying to develop a Backbone Marionette application and I need to know how to do CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Destroy) actions in the best way. I cannot find any resources explaining this (only for Backbone).

Any examples out there?

Comment: please more links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marionette is a library on top of Backbone think about it like jQueryUI for jQuery and aims to help you to scale your aplication allowing you to modularize it, among other things like saving you from writing a lot of repetitive code. 
So there wont a lot of CRUD exameples, the exampels will try to prove the benefits of marionette.

however I think this two tutorials will help you.

http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/
http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/22/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial-part-2/

http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/05/06/tutorial-a-full-backbone-marionette-application-part-1/
http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/05/13/tutorial-a-full-backbone-marionette-application-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

You can find a more advanced CRUD application example here:

https://github.com/nuragic/marionette-bootstrap

It illustrates (among other things) how to structure your application with  "modules".